# Video Background plugin - mute video - Wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, video

I have created a website using Wordpress and have installed a plugin called `VideoBackground`. On my homepage, the video plays with NO sound. If I go to the source of the video, it plays with sound.

I have tried to change the JS to set the default `mute:false`, and have also checked it with Google's dev tools and saw that the Video HTML says `muted=""` which I assume means it's not being muted. Any idea why the sound won't play?

Thank you so much in advance for the help!

LINK TO SITE: zuited.co

EDIT: When I add a "tap to unmute" button through the plugin, it will unmute successfully when I press the button. I'd like for it to default to unmuted without a button.

Comment: Share the plugin link

Comment: Plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/video-background/
Theme: https://oceanwp.org/

Comment: If you read the instructions and check the screen-shots then you must find there is a way to mute the video - http://prntscr.com/jr27bs

Answer (score 0):

This plugin is providing a way to mute the video

`[vidbg container="body" mp4="#" webm="#" poster="#" muted="true" loop="true" overlay="false" overlay_color="#000" overlay_alpha="0.3"]`

Also you can see the option in screen-shot - http://prntscr.com/jr27bs